# React Native Flatlist rerendering lag due to appcontext

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have a Flatlist that uses a value from my AppContext. Everytime I update my textinput, my Flatlists completely rerender causing lots of lag. I have tried using useMemo in my app context with almost 0 difference I think I am doing something wrong.

AppContext.js:

```
const initialState = {
    searchedShoes: [],
};

const AppContext = createContext();
function useAppContext() {
    console.log("this is useAppContext");
    return useContext(AppContext);
};

function AppProvider({ children }) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    // rest of AppProvider functions and code....
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={useMemo(
                () => ({ ...state, getShoes, getSavedShoes, addSavedShoe, removeSavedShoe, displayErrorTemporary }),
                [state]
            )}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

File thats lagging:

```
function AddShoe({ addingShoe, setAddingShoe }) {
  
  const appContextValues = useAppContext();
  const { getShoes, searchedShoes, displayErrorTemporary, error } = appContextValues;
  const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect runs");
    getShoes();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
      <Modal visible={addingShoe} animationType="slide">
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={styles.container}>

              <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <TextInput style={styles.searchBar} placeholder={"Shoe name"} autoCorrect={false} onChangeText={setSelectedName} />
              </View>

              <FlatList
                style={styles.shoeDisplay}
                data={searchedShoes}
                numColumns={2}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  return <ShoeContainer key={item._id} shoe={item} />;
              }} />
              <Button text={"Cancel"} onPress={() => setAddingShoe(false)} />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

I have tried useMemo to no avail. The problem is not caused by useEffect since I console.log'd it and it only runs once. Also, the console.log in useAppContext ran around 50 times which is how many items i have in my "searchedShoes" array so that might be the problem but i am not sure how to fix it.